# What happened to Terran Michael Burnham?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

What happened to the Terran version of Michael Burnham in *Star Trek: Discovery*? The emperor seemed to believe that she could be alive.

Answer (score 3):

According the prequel *Star Trek: Discovery* comic miniseries, ***Succession*** [Mirror Burnham](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Burnham_(mirror)) was killed.

> In the Star Trek: Discovery comic miniseries, Succession it was
>   revealed that Burnham pretended ally with Lorca, in order to stop his
>   plans. However, she could not reveal her plans to Georgiou. Burnham
>   then hid herself on Risa and waited for her moment to strike. She
>   eventually took the mantle of Empress from Georgiou's cousin Alexander
>   (β). **However, Burnham was killed by Airiam (β) who then succeeded
>   her as Empress.**

Comment: What about the final episode with Georgiou? That would seem to contradict this.

Comment: Ya, I think you're right the information has been "updated" per season 3 finale, but I would need to watch the episode again/go to Star Trek wiki just to get my facts straight. I will come back and make an edit soon..